# Contributing to existing packages

Tags: best-practices, package-writing

This is something I've been considering for a while with respect to some code I've got that adds to `acronym` (nothing clever, just handling a few more use cases, it's almost all online here at tex.se).

But I was reading today about the [`bclogo` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bclogo) which only has French documentation.  My French isn't great but I can read enough to translate a document like that. There isn't actually all that much text considering the manual is over 30 pages.

So in general what do package authors/maintainers think about random users contacting them with contributions that are *hopefully* easy to integrate (but some effort is likely to be needed)? I assume that the "contact author" link on CTAN would be the way to go.  I don't particularly want to promise at a first contact to deliver something that I'm going to be working on in odd moments, neither do I want to waste time (especially someone else's) on duplication of effort.

I know we have some very experienced package authors here.  For the example of contributing *code* that extends an existing package, what makes it easiest for the maintainer to integrate?

Comment: It is worth a try to contact the package author, seeking collaboration.  For example, in the `listofitems` package, I am in charge of the English translation, while Christian handles the French. He had sworn he would never write another package with English documentation, so it worked out well.  I am not sure if this question more properly belongs on the meta site...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Another Christian could provide a German translation ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, if I do say so myself, it is a great package worthy of translation into many languages. `;^)`

Comment: Best would be indeed to contact the author and to have the translation as part of the package. But if this cannot be achieved, there is also the possibility to have translated manuals as separate packages like [`translation-biblatex-de`](http://ctan.org/pkg/translation-biblatex-de). Almost same for package extensions. If they cannot be added to the package, sometimes a wrapper package could be a solution.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I wondered about meta too, but felt it was better here as meta is more about tex.*stackexchange* business. But if there's a consensus that this is better there I'm happy with that too.

Comment: note the "contact author" link doesn't contact anyone: it just offers advice such as read the documentation to find a contact address (which often isn't there in my experience)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's a good (if surprising) point. In both my example cases the authors do have email addresses in the docs or somewhere else sensible.

Comment: when big luatex updates broke existing packages we tried to find people to agree to minor updates, in some cases it took weeks to find usable contact address (in some cases by guessing github user names and hopefully pinging there in that system to see if the right people responded:-)

Comment: to be honest I suspect that the question should be closed as too broad or opinion-based  it doesn't really fit the site format, (although I've not actually voted to close, let the comments run a bit)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see where you're coming from with that. I'll consider whether I can make it a little more concrete.

Answer (score 3):

It all boils down to the question, if the source code is published on a platform like github, sf.net, whatever, or even on his own homepage. If yes, use that site. Many maintainers are glad to get feedback.

If no github and no homepage, write an Email.

(One question less without any answer. New game. Come and help.)